# Execute Function After Saving PostgreSQL Layer - QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, layers, database

I have a QGIS project with many PostgreSQL layers. One of these layers is the result of processing some other layers. So each time any of the other layers are modified in any way that layer should be processed.

The way I used to do it was by executing a trigger on PostgreSQL after insert/update/delete of any rows of those layers to start the process. But it has a drawbar. For example, if I insert multiple features and then save the layer, for each of these new layers that trigger function will be executed which is not something I want. I want the function to be executed after each save (so once for every layer save in QGIS which might have added multiple features).

Is there any way to execute a Python function in QGIS or a PostgreSQL function after saving new changes of layers in QGIS (hitting `Save for All Layers`)?

Comment: A `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger should do just that - given that QGIS does batch `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`'s.

Comment: @geozelot tried it. doesn't do the trick. runs it for every features.